# Does this kind of bag have a specific name?

Tags: terminology, image-identification

[image: Drawstring bag]

Does this kind of bag have a specific name in the English language?

Comment: It's called a *drawstring bag*;

Answer (score 7):

I would define that bag as a [Drawstring Pouch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pouch) based on it's appearance and suspected purpose.

[Look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=drawstring+pouch&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidwoTy-bLQAhVqsFQKHZCKBgoQ_AUICSgC&biw=1410&bih=930) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=drawstring+coin+pouch&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidwoTy-bLQAhVqsFQKHZCKBgoQ_AUICSgC&biw=1410&bih=930) for some additional examples of pouches.

Comment: Drawstring pouch or drawstring bag are both good

Answer (score 0):

Names vary, but they are usually called

> (medieval) drawstring *(money) pouch* or *(coin) purse*